# Operations over list of ints with template metaprogramming [C++11]

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I have implementation of list of ints with template:

```
template<int ... Int>
struct IntList;

template<int H, int ... T>
struct IntList<H, T...>{
    static const int Head = H;
    using Tail = IntList<T...>;
};
template<>
struct IntList<>{};
```

I want to define metafunctions to work with `IntList`: `IntCons` that allows to increase list by one element, and `Generate` that allows to generate a list of length N with ints from 0 to N-1 (*Example of usage:* `using L = Generate<5>::type; // IntList<0,1,2,3,4>)`.
I define `IntCons` this way:

```
template<int H, typename IL>
struct IntCons;

template<int H, int... Tail>
struct IntCons<H, IntList<Tail...>>{
    using type = IntList<H, Tail...>;
};
```

And i can't define metafunction `Generate` in such way that use function `IntCons` inside.
Here's hint, according to i need use default parameter in `Generate`.

```
template<int N /*, typename IL =  default parameter?*/ >
struct Generate;

template<int N /*, typename IL =  default parameter?*/ >
struct Generate<N>{
    using type = ......;
};
```

What are the ways to define the meta-function Generate, how can i implement it?

Comment: What'd you try? What doesn't work?

Comment: @Barry i don't understand what i need to do, so i didn,'t try so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Generate` is very similar to `std::make_index_sequence`; maybe you can search an implementation.

Just for fun, I propose the following linear approach (simple but not really efficient)

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int ...>
struct IntList
 { };

template <int N, int ... Next>
struct Generate : public Generate<N-1, N-1, Next...>
 { };

template <int ... Next>
struct Generate<0, Next ... >
 { using type = IntList<Next ... >; };

int main()
 {
   static_assert( std::is_same<Generate<5>::type,
                               IntList<0, 1, 2, 3, 4>>{}, "!" );
 }
```

A better approach (but not so simple) can be the following (logarithmic)

```
template <int...>
struct IntList
 { };

template <typename, typename>
struct ConcatLists;

template <int ... S1, int ... S2>
struct ConcatLists<IntList<S1...>, IntList<S2...>>
 { using type = IntList<S1..., (sizeof...(S1)+S2)...>; };

template <int N>
struct Generate
 { using type = typename ConcatLists<
      typename Generate<(N>>1)>::type,
      typename Generate<N-(N>>1)>::type>::type; };

template<>
struct Generate<0>
 { using type = IntList<>; };

template<>
struct Generate<1>
 { using type = IntList<0>; };

int main()
 {
   static_assert( std::is_same<Generate<5>::type,
                               IntList<0, 1, 2, 3, 4>>{}, "!" );    
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask

> thank you. Please, can you explain how first example works? I don't understand how works this line: `template <int N, int ... Next> struct Generate : public Generate<N-1, N-1, Next...> { };`

I think the best way to understand it is follows the chain that, from `Generate<5>`, bring to `Inlist<0, 1, 2, 3, 4>`.

`Generate<5>` (`5` is different from `0` so only the main version of `Generate` is applicable) inherit (`N` is `5`; `Next...` is empty) from `Generate<4, 4>`.

`Generate<4, 4>` (`4` is different from `0`) inherit (`N` is `5`; `Next...` is `4`) from `Generate<3, 3, 4>`.

Now should be clear.

`Generate<3, 3, 4>` inherit from `Generate<2, 2, 3, 4>`.

`Generate<2, 2, 3, 4>` inherit from `Generate<1, 1, 2, 3, 4>`.

`Generate<1, 1, 2, 3, 4>` inherit from `Generate<0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4>`.

Now `N` is zero. So both versions of `Generate` match but the partial specialization (`struct Generate<0, Next ... >`) is more specialized and is the used one and (`Next...` is `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`) we have

```
struct Generate<0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4>
 { using type = IntList<0, 1, 2, 3, 4>; };
```

Conclusion: `Generate<5>` inherit from `Generate<0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4>` that contains `type` defined as `IntList<0, 1, 2, 3, 4>`.

Comment: thank you. Please, can you explain how first example works? I don't understand how  works this line:                               template <int N, int ... Next>
struct Generate : public Generate<N-1, N-1, Next...>
 { };

Comment: @user1786089 - answer improved; hope this helps.